# Group by and Self Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure

```
Txn_id Varchar
Role   Varchar
Acid   Varchar
RefTxt Varchar
```

Now the RefTxt column will only contain data when the Role column is of type 'Transporter'. Role can also take up the values 'Sender' and 'Receiver'

I want to query the table in such a way that I get the following output

```
Txn_id   Sender_Acid   Reciever_Acid
Tx001    SAC001        RAC001
```

For this I have written the query

```
SELECT
    myTable.Txn_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Sender' THEN myTable.acid END)    AS sender_acid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Recipient' THEN myTable.acid END) AS recipient_acid

FROM 
    myTable,
    (
      SELECT txn_id, reftext
      FROM   myTable
      WHERE  role = 'Transporter'
    ) SubQuery
WHERE     SubQuery.txn_id = myTable.txn_id
AND       myTable.role in ('Sender', 'Receiver')
GROUP BY  mytable.txn_id;
```

I expected the result to contain a single row per txn_id with the fields Sender_Acid and Receiver_Acid containing the respective accounts. However for some Txn_id I am getting two separate rows which have either the Sender_acid or the receiver_acid as NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your query, but you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT myTable.Txn_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Sender' THEN myTable.acid END)    AS sender_acid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Recipient' THEN myTable.acid END) AS recipient_acid
FROM myTable join
     myTable Subquery
     on SubQuery.txn_id = myTable.txn_id and
        Subquery.role = 'Transporter'
WHERE myTable.role in ('Sender', 'Receiver')
GROUP BY  mytable.txn_id;
```

If you are getting two rows for what look like the same `Txn_id`, it is because those ids are really different.  Perhaps one is ending in spaces.  To see this, try this `select`:

```
select '|'||myTable.Txn_id||'|',
```

That will put vertical bars around the id so you can see any extra characters.